# Factor a specific sub-polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, expression-manipulation, term-rewriting

Consider the following example for a polynomial in several variables:

```
pol = x^2 y + x^4 z + x^3 y z + x^6 y z^2 + x y^2 z^2 + x^5 y^2 z^2 + x^5 z^3 + x^4 y z^3 + x^3 y^3 z^3 + x^2 y^4 z^3 + x^2 y^2 z^4 + x^4 y^5 z^4 + x^3 y^4 z^5;
```

Let's say I have a suspicion that this polynomial or a part of it should factor into two sub-polynomials, one of which I guess to be `factor = (x^2 z^3 + y x^3 z^2 + x z)`. I would like to have a function that explicitly finds the factorization:

```
FactorSubpol[pol,factor]
```

> x^2 y + (x^3 + x^2 y + x y^4 z^2 + y^2 z) (x^2 z^3 + y x^3 z^2 + x z)

in case if such a factorization is possible, and returns the unfactorized terms in `pol` if such a factorization is impossible. I have tried `Collect[pol,factor]`, but it only seems to work with very simple `factor` expressions. Is there a way to do the above consistently with larger factors? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
res = Rest@Select[Subsets@pol, PolynomialMod[#, factor] == 0 &]
```

So, out of the 8192 `(== 2^13)` possible "sub-polys", only these ones are divisible by `factor`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[Join[{{"pol == Non-factored", "Plus (factor by ...)"}}, 
           {pol - # factor // Expand, #} & /@ (PolynomialQuotient[#, factor, z] & /@ 
            res)], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
pol = x^2 y + x^4 z + x^3 y z + x^6 y z^2 + x y^2 z^2 + x^5 y^2 z^2 + 
   x^5 z^3 + x^4 y z^3 + x^3 y^3 z^3 + x^2 y^4 z^3 + x^2 y^2 z^4 + 
   x^4 y^5 z^4 + x^3 y^4 z^5;

guess = (x^2 z^3 + y x^3 z^2 + x z);

FullSimplify[pol/guess]*Simplify[guess]
```

> x*z*(1 + x^2*y*z + x*z^2)*    (x^2*(x + y) + (x*y)/z + y^2*z + 
>         x*y^4*z^2 - (x^2*y*(x*y + z))/
>           (1 + x*z*(x*y + z)))

Consequently, your `guess` is not a factor of `pol`